# DatabaseFactory not initialized - Sqflite error on Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to run a flutter app on Web, this app uses sqflite and whenever any database related method hits (query, initialization etc), i am getting this error:

```
Bad state: databaseFactory not initialized
databaseFactory is only initialized when using sqflite. When using `sqflite_common_ffi`
You must call `databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;` before using global openDatabase API
```

I read the documentation of sfqlite and it appears that it does not support flutter web. I want to know if is there any work around for this? If yes, then please could some one guide me

Thanks

I have found some packages that are Drift and sqflite_common_ffi_web, i have not tried to implement them because it is going to be a hard task for me.